# Request Pending After A DELETE request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, axios, crud

I am working with Reactjs and I am having and issue while sending request, Last week everthing was working perfectly and then I started to face that request issue.
When I send GET, PUT, POST request everything works fine with no problems, when I send a DELETE request it gets sent and I recieve a response with status 204, but any type of request I send after, it stucks in a pending state forever and never reaches the backend server.
I tired different Projets same issue, different PC same issue.
When I access my dev server from another PC everythings works perfectly no problems, seem like the  problem happens only when I send request from the same machine where the dev server is strated.
I pulled an old version of the code where I was sure everything were fine and I got same issue, I tried to empty cache, different browsers, I event emptied my whole disk and installed windows again.
I tried the DELETE request with Postman and it stucked in pending state.
I tried different backends same problem.
The Back-end is with Django, I Don't have access the back-end code but I tried same proccess with Postman and there was no issue.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
api
    .delete(`objet/front/${feature.get("featureID")}/`)
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 204) {
                layer.getSource().removeFeature(feature);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try checking that resource, which you are trying to delete is still present on the server, if that is getting deleted then you just need to send the request with timeout of 5 or 10 sec and if something goes wrong, it will be logged in the console as you have used catch in the code.

Try this:

```
api
  .delete(`objet/front/${feature.get("featureID")}/`, {
    timeout: 10000, // Set timeout to 10 or 5 seconds
  })
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.status === 204) {
      layer.getSource().removeFeature(feature);
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Log the error you get to the console
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Yea the the resource is getting deleted, I tried and set Timeout to axois nothing changed, 
I don't think the problem is in Axios, because even when i used postman, the request never got fully satisfied, and what's weird, when I access the dev-server from another machine it works fine

Comment: what do you mean by access the dev-server from another machine? are you hitting the delete api using different machine?

Comment: I have the Dev server started  on Machine "X" and accessed to that server Using Machine "Y" whiche are localy connected, on the "Y" machine everything works fine, however on the "X" the problems happens

Comment: I tried recreating the issue but it's working fine for me, you need to check your backend code.

Comment: I don't think is a code problem, because I tried some backends that has been working for a while and same issues